Dafny loop with a return in it
How do I prove the following Dafny program?
method return_loop() returns (r:int)
ensures r == 5
{
  var i := 0;
  while i < 10
    invariant 0<= i <= 10
  {
    if i == 5{
       return i;
    }
    i := i + 1;
  }
  return i;
 }

I read the similar post What does Dafny know about loops with a break?, but still can't prove the above program.

I added a found flag, and it worked:
method return_loop() returns (r:int)
  ensures r == 5
{
  var i := 0;
  var n := 10;
  var found := false;
  while i < n
  decreases n - i
  invariant 0<= i <= n
  {
    if i == 5{
       found := true;
       return i;
    }
    i := i + 1;
  }
  assert (!found  ==> r != 5) || (found && r == 5);
  return i;
}

Is there a better way of proving this?

Actually, I got it working without the found flag. But the forall gives me a Could not find a trigger for this quantifier warning, which I could not fix.
method return_loop() returns (r:int)
  ensures r == 5
{
  var i := 0;
  var n := 10;
  while i < n
  decreases n - i
  invariant 0 <= i <= n
  invariant forall k:int:: 0 < k < i ==> k != 5
  {
    if i == 5{
       return i;
    }
    i := i + 1;
  }
  return i;
}

method Test(){
  var x := return_loop();
  assert x == 5;
}

